# Creating a diagonal line/section/border with CSS

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design, css-shapes

I am trying to create a diagonal line on a webpage, to act as a section/section break. This is essentially a split colour section. I cant use an image as if the page gets enlarged, the image is going to pixelate. So i need to be able to draw a diagonal line directly at the bottom of the div, like the image below.

I have tried using a border, however i cannot get the actual break to be in the middle, rather than the right or left hand side.

Is there a way to draw diagonal lines in CSS? As you can see, i need to create a div that is 90px high and have the split/diagonal line in that div. I can then have a look at adding the image, but the main issue is not knowing whether this is possible with CSS.

[image: Diagonal section separator]

Comment: _“I cant use an image as if the page gets enlarged, the image is going to pixelate”_ – so you never heard of SVG then …?

Comment: Thanks for your constructive and helping comment

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With an svg, it is pretty simple :

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon points="100 0 100 10 0 10" />
</svg>
```

*Note that I used the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute so that the shape can have 100% width and keep 90px height*

And here with a monkey image :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: yellow;
}
img {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="100 0 100 10 0 10" />
  </svg>
  <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/monkey-clipart-black-and-white-16981-monkey-face-svg.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: @DomGreensladeBSc this works in latest FF  and according to canIuse it should also work on much older versions. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Sorry, on something completely different. What if i wanted to invert this? In terms of the polygon that is. I have updated the image on the main question, i attempted to draw a polygon, but cant see how this works.

Comment: @DomGreensladeBSc the easiest would be to invert the colors like this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3ku7npf8/

Comment: Sorry, i meant almost invert the polygon like the image in the question now.

Comment: @DomGreensladeBSc if you want it like the image you edited into the question, see this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3ku7npf8/1/

Comment: how do you go about changing the colour of the bottom part of the segment?

Comment: @DomGreensladeBSc just change the svg background color in the CSS.

Comment: @DomGreensladeBSc the top color is controled by the `fill` attribute in the markup and the bottom one is controled by the background color in the CSS http://jsfiddle.net/3ku7npf8/2/

Answer (score 17):

You can do this without any clipping and just using borders in a unique way. This should also be cross-browser compatible, but I haven't tested it across everything

Initially divided this into 2 separate divs / triangles and joined them, but thanks to `web-tiki` and `kaiido` perfected it to use only 1 div and minimal CSS

```css
*{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#gradient {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 90px 100vw 0 0;
  border-color: yellow black transparent transparent;
  transform: scale(1.0001);
}
```

```html
<div id="gradient"></div>
```

**Original Answer using multiple divs:**

```css
*{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#container div {
  position: absolute;
}

#top-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 90px 100vw 0 0;
  border-color: yellow transparent transparent transparent;
}

#bottom-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 90px 100vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top-triangle"></div>
  <div id="bottom-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why use three divs when only one is enough? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/jLa8sfp7/

Comment: I would add to @web-tiki that you can also add a `transform: scale(1.0001);`to remove that crispy edge : http://jsfiddle.net/jLa8sfp7/3/

Comment: @web-tiki oh yeah - good point. For some reason I just didn't think about that - instead I was thinking of it from the standpoint of joing 2 triangles.

Comment: I did this, and the line looked really really jagged.

Comment: @DomGreensladeBSc did you add the `transform: scale(1.001)`? If you did, then you can use my original answer which does a better job of removing the jaggedness.

Comment: This solution only works good on fullscreen divs.
If used inside a smaller div, it doesn't fit the parent width.

Answer (score 8):

Use a linear gradient

```css
div {
  height: 90px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, yellow 50%, black 50%, black);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS3 `clip`:

```css
.yellow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
}
.black {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 99%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 99%);
  margin-top: -90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zLkrfeev/2/

It's not widely supported by the browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a gradient.

```
body {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image:
     -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 14px);
  background-image:
     -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 14px);
  background-image:
     -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 14px);
  background-image:
     repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 14px);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9eUU/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put diagonal border in column you can do it this way and its 100% responsive. your requirement might be different though. I put it transparent image which contains white diagonal border in that section's right column.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="h-row">
    <div class="h-left">
    </div>
    <div class="h-right">
      <div class="hr-box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.h-row{display: table; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
.h-left,
.h-right{display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; height:250px;}/*height is just for demo purpose you can remove it ofcourse and fill the content */ 
.h-left{background: #e9eae2; padding: 50px 83px 15px 165px; width: 69%;}
.h-right{background: #7acec3 url('https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAMv9WREPIx2AXUVhzCrK5Hl1jxf3ofX0teck9P94bG_SCjB28QPmKqXuchYyjp_xFMjMrGLzRYHh0O9wBOZJMZW9L_97lScKB22dgco9eGMJ1PCBbFepUcDkPg3aUE_1ONik2rKQ2SgRvtUgdq8nA_Ev1gxLxq8yWcXNKOdxKGBNOqe4FTHnbAgGy-JD4UtwZliw8c0fmNah8rydlD4JetFxNubkUyW4I_Q-XRL5qjW9A/p.png?size=1280x960&size_mode=3') no-repeat center center/ 100% 100%; padding: 50px 165px 15px 0; width: 31%; position: relative;}
.h-left .row{margin:0 -44px;}
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/neel555nc/pen/LgjoOg