# using z-index and diagonal items inside of a table <td> element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to "hide" any overflow from a diagonal line inside of a table <td> element.

example:   https://jsfiddle.net/edwardsmarkf/8zuk6naL/47/

```
span#diagLine {
  transform: rotate(345deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  position: absolute;
  ...........
  z-index: -100;  /* does not do anything!  */
  overflow: hidden; /* does not do anything!  */
}
```

In my example copied [from here](https://9elements.com/blog/pure-css-diagonal-layouts/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015781/creating-a-diagonal-line-section-border-with-css),the **z-index** does not seem to work for me even though the position is *absolute* as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671013/z-index-is-not-working-inside-table).  And the **overflow** property does not appear to work for me either.

It behaves as if a diagonal line is special and the CSS properties no longer apply to it.

I was unable to find any SO suggestions that apply to a diagonal line inside of a table <td> element.

I could probably do something with jScript, but was hoping for a pure CSS solution, hopefully with just minimal changes.  Or maybe I have missed something very obvious?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

ok I figure out you can use a class (.bottom) for the "seeable" td

check this out

```
span#diagLine {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(345deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  position: absolute;
  display:relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index:-10;
}

td.styleTableTdItem {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 1; 
   
}

td:not(.bottom){
  background-color:white
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s23fhdbe/1/

Comment: your jsfiddle does not totally hide the excess, it just moves it outside the table. 
i was hoping to completely hide it?  but you are on the right track for sure!
https://jsfiddle.net/s23fhdbe/1/

Comment: i looked like that because i wrote added another td and a longer diagonal text. yet still thinking in a fancier solution  https://jsfiddle.net/qxLj64er/

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this if you are dealing only with the elements shown in the example
td:last-child{
background-color:white
}